# Parent Div to Keep the Height of Tallest Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been Googling potential solutions but as yet cannot find one that fits the brief.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">I'm 60px tall and visible; my parent is 100px tall</div>
    <div class="child2">I'm 80px tall and hidden until needed</div>
    <div class="child3">I'm 100px tall and hidden until needed</div>
</div>
```

- I need to have a number of child Divs with a parent Div.
- Only one child will show at any time.
- The parent Div must always remain the same height as the tallest child and never expand or
  contract.

I'll use jQuery to change the css of the visible child but I'd prefer a CSS solution to the height if possible.

No IE8/9/10 to support.

Anyone got ideas?

Comment: What you want is pretty easy in **jQuery**, but I have a doubt usinf **CSS**

Comment: try to give display flex to parent div(if child as column). but if child stack one after each other then it need jQuery solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is what you want:

1. Use `flex` display to arrange the child as column display.
2. Set their `opacity` as 0 so that the child element still remain in the parent div, this will set the parent height the same as the tallest child.
3. Created a new class `visible` to style the visible child, and set default children (which are hidden) `width: 0px` while visible child will have `width: 100%`

```js
function show(element) {
  $('.parent div').removeClass('visible');
  $('.' + element).addClass('visible');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  display: flex;
}

.child1 {
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  height: 80px;
  background: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

.parent div {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
}

.parent div.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1 visible">I'm 60px tall and visible; my parent is 100px tall</div>
  <div class="child2">I'm 80px tall and hidden until needed</div>
  <div class="child3">I'm 100px tall and hidden until needed</div>
</div>

<br/>
<button onclick="show('child1')">Child 1</button>
<button onclick="show('child2')">Child 2</button>
<button onclick="show('child3')">Child 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

hide using `opacity` with `0` and `1` and the parent should be as tall as the tallest child.

See snippet below

```js
$(function(){ 
  $(".c").fadeTo(0,0);
  $(".child1").fadeTo(0,1).addClass("visible");
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".c").fadeTo(0,0);
    $(".visible").removeClass("visible").next().fadeTo(0,1).addClass("visible");
  });

});
```

```css
.parent { position:relative; border:2px solid red; display:flex  }
.c { border:2px solid blue; }
.child1 { height:60px; }
.child2 { height:80px; }
.child3 { height:100px; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="c child1">I'm 60px tall and visible; my parent is 100px tall</div>
    <div class="c child2">I'm 80px tall and hidden until needed</div>
    <div class="c child3">I'm 100px tall and hidden until needed</div>
</div>

<button class="btn">Show Next Child</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```